# Вывод изображения

Tags: php

Вопрос не сложный. Хочу сделать чтобы выполнялось условие, если в БД ['small'] == 0 то выполняется вывод картинки не из БД, а из определенной папки. Например из /foto/no_photo/no_photo_s.png Как правильно сделать вывод фиксированной картинки из папки?

```
echo '<td align=center valign=top width="100">';
            if($row_Recordset1['small'])
            echo '<img class="imground" src="'.$bp.$row_Recordset1['small'].'" border=0>';
            elseif ($row_Recordset1['video_host'] == 'youtu.be' || $row_Recordset1['video_host']=='youtube.com')
            echo '<img class="imground" width=100 src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/'.$row_Recordset1['video_item'].'/1.jpg" border=0>';
elseif($row_Recordset1['small'] == 0){
echo '<img class="imground" src="'.$bp.$row_Recordset1['small'].'" border=0>';
```

Comment: Вопрос то собственно в чем?

Comment: if осталось вверху...

это финальная строка. Хотелось бы увидеть вариант из папки /foto/no_photo/no_photo_s.png

Comment: @Serg1234, даже, если "*if осталось вверху*", то для дополнительного условия, синтаксис должен быть такой:

    if(условие_первое){
        // что-то делаем
    } elseif($row_Recordset1['small'] == 0){
        echo '<img class="imground" src="'.$bp.$row_Recordset1['small'].'" border=0>';
    }

Comment: Привел более полный кусок...

Comment: Я так понимаю, что изображение не выводится, а **$bp** - это что-то вроде "*base path*". Могу предположить, что проблема может быть именно в этом **$bp**. Выведите на экран конкатенацию этих переменных. Возможно, что не хватает слэша и нужно прописывать так:

    $bp.'/'.$row_Recordset1['small'];

А вообще, для теста, можно написать так:

   echo '<img class="imground" src="'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$row_Recordset1['small'].'" border=0>';

Comment: Deonis Спасибо тест помог...